# Is there a nice way to add new box and redraw the canvas using javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

The underlying code creates random blocks in the canvas.
This is what I've achieved so far. But I'm having difficulty in doing further task. I want to make a button outside the canvas(definitely that's easy) on clicking which a new box is added in canvas. The position of old box may or may not change(its upto providing proper room). If there is not enough room for the new box increase the size of inner container which will increase the size of canvas and redraw the old box(es) by the new canvas scale with the new one. And If inner container size increases the outer container, a scroll bar will come in outer container.
This is my current code:

Html:

```
<div class="outer-container">
    <div class="inner-container">
        <canvas id="canvas" style="height:100%;width:100%"></canvas>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
function getRandomColor() {
    var color = '#';
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        color += (Math.random() * 16 | 0).toString(16);
    }
    return color;
}

function Point(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

function Rectangle(p1, p2) {
    this.p1 = p1;
    this.p2 = p2;
}

Rectangle.prototype.isInside = function (r) {
    function check(a, b) {
        return (
            a.p1.x <= b.p1.x && b.p1.x <= a.p2.x && a.p1.y <= b.p1.y && b.p1.y <= a.p2.y ||
            a.p1.x <= b.p2.x && b.p2.x <= a.p2.x && a.p1.y <= b.p2.y && b.p2.y <= a.p2.y ||
            a.p1.x <= b.p2.x && b.p2.x <= a.p2.x && a.p1.y <= b.p1.y && b.p1.y <= a.p2.y ||
            a.p1.x <= b.p1.x && b.p1.x <= a.p2.x && a.p1.y <= b.p2.y && b.p2.y <= a.p2.y
        );
    }
    return check(this, r) || check(r, this);
}

function generateRectangles() {
    function p() { return Math.random() * 300 | 0; }
    function s() { return 50 + Math.random() * 150 | 0; }

    var rectangles = [],
        r, size, x, y, isInside, i, counter = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        counter = 0;
        do {
            counter++;
            x = p();
            y = p();
            size = s();
            r = new Rectangle(new Point(x, y), new Point(x + size, y + size));
            isInside = rectangles.some(function (a) {
                return a.isInside(r);
            });
        } while (isInside && counter < 1000);
        counter < 1000 && rectangles.push(r);
    }
    return rectangles;
}

function drawRectangles(rectangles) {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
        ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    rectangles.forEach(function (a) {
        ctx.lineWidth = 1;
        ctx.strokeRect(a.p1.x + 0.5, a.p1.y + 0.5, a.p2.x - a.p1.x - 1, a.p2.y - a.p1.y - 1);
        ctx.fillStyle = getRandomColor();
        ctx.fillRect(a.p1.x + 0.5, a.p1.y + 0.5, a.p2.x - a.p1.x - 1, a.p2.y - a.p1.y - 1);
    });
}

var rectangles = generateRectangles();
drawRectangles(rectangles);
```

I just don't know how will I redraw it. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What is or is not working with your current code?  Also, understand that you will always have to track and do logic for box resizing yourself.  Canvas is just a way to rasterize content to the screen.  It won't size content for you; it's effectively one-way in that respect.  Yes, you can get pixels out of it, but all of the context about those pixels will be gone.

Comment: What do you mean: *"The position of old box may or may not change (its up to providing proper room)"*?. Your `drawRectangles` function already draws each rectangle in `rectangles[]`. So you can (1) Hit test your possible new Rectangle, (2) `rectangles.push` your `new Rectangle...` into `rectangles`, (3) clear the canvas, (4) resize containers and canvas if necessary (use overflow scroll on the container if necessary), & (5) call `drawRectangles`. BTW, don't resize your canvas element with CSS -- that will squeeze and/or stretch your rectangles. Instead, resize the canvas element itself.

Comment: When asking questions about canvas and describing the behaviour as above, I suggest to always add a screenshot or alike, it makes it much easier to other people to quickly get the idea. I also suggest that you put a working sample of what you have in codepen.io or alike.

Answer (score 0):

Create button, with an   **onclick="draw();"**   attribute, and a javascript  **draw()**  function to draw whatever you want.